# Проблема при компиляции PHP 7

Tags: debian, php7, компиляция

Сама проблема:

```
cc: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1)
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <file:///usr/share/doc/gcc-4.9/README.Bugs> for instructions.
Makefile:733: recipe for target 'ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo' failed
make: *** [ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo] Error 1
```

Как её решить ?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема найдена

```
RAM < 512 mb
```

Придётся искать альтернативный способ установки.